# Upgrading GeoTools

Tags: geotools

Currently we are using GeoTools release version **2.7.5**. I checked the versioning of GeoTools and found that, there is a stable release version 8.* directly after 2.7.*. Do the new release versions (according to current date **10.4** [GeoTools Blog](http://geotoolsnews.blogspot.de/)) always mean the up-to-date version or different release versions serve different purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [blog post](http://geotoolsnews.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/geotools-8.html) from 2011 explains the change, basically we dropped the 2 from the version numbers to reflect the actual real world process that was occurring. Currently [10.4](http://geotoolsnews.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/geotools-104-released.html) is the latest stable release.

> GeoTools jars are versioned as a group with version numbers are based
>   on 3 digits::
>
> `<major>.<minor>.<patch>`
>
> - Major (first digit), is incremented to indicate that a module has lost full compatibility to earlier versions.
>
>   So you can safely upgrade to later versions of a module so long as
>     the major version has not changed.
> - Minor (second digit) is incremented whenever new features are added.
>
>   Modules are forward compatible across minor versions, but usually
>     not backward compatible.
> - Patch (last digit) is for bug fixes.
>
>   It is used to indicate fixes in bugs only. No new features were made
>     and full compatibility is preserved.
>
> GeoTools jars released from trunk are versioned with version number
>   based on 2 digits::
>
> ```
> <major>.<minor>-M<milestone>
> <major>.<minor>-RC<candidate>
> ```
>
> - Milestone is used to mark alpha or beta releases as appropriate (example 8.0-M1)
> - Release Candidates are marked 8.0-RC1 and indicate that the branch has been forked   off trunk in preparation for final release.